# Tomcat and Java upgrade causing CPU spikes during CMS major collections

Tags: java, concurrency, cpu

Recently we upgraded the `Java (1.6.0_18->1.6.0_38)` and `Tomcat (6.0.32->7.0.34)` versions of a third party `J2EE` web application that runs in our production environment.  We soon received alerts that the CPU on the server was spiking over 50% a couple of times a day.  Upon further analysis, I observed that the spikes were taking place at the same time as the Concurrent Mark Sweep major gc’s, and that the total CPU time required to complete them had greatly increased, particularly in the CMS-concurrent-mark and CMS-concurrent-sweep phases:

Before:

```
2013-03-08T14:36:49.861-0500: 553875.681: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 4152134K(8303424K)] 4156673K(8380096K), 0.0067893 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:36:49.868-0500: 553875.688: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2013-03-08T14:36:55.682-0500: 553881.503: [GC 553881.503: [ParNew: 72675K->4635K(76672K), 0.0322031 secs] 4224809K->4157567K(8380096K), 0.0327540 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:36:58.224-0500: 553884.045: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 8.320/8.356 secs] [Times: user=9.18 sys=0.02, real=8.36 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:36:58.224-0500: 553884.045: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2013-03-08T14:36:58.276-0500: 553884.097: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.051/0.052 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:36:58.277-0500: 553884.097: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2013-03-08T14:37:01.458-0500: 553887.279: [GC 553887.279: [ParNew: 72795K->4887K(76672K), 0.0332472 secs] 4225727K->4158532K(8380096K), 0.0337703 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2013-03-08T14:37:03.296-0500: 553889.117: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.462/5.020 secs] [Times: user=2.04 sys=0.02, real=5.02 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:37:03.299-0500: 553889.119: [GC[YG occupancy: 22614 K (76672 K)]553889.120: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0151518 secs]553889.135: [weak refs processing, 0.0356825 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 4153644K(8303424K)] 4176259K(8380096K), 0.0620445 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:37:03.363-0500: 553889.183: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2013-03-08T14:37:07.248-0500: 553893.069: [GC 553893.069: [ParNew: 73047K->5136K(76672K), 0.0510894 secs] 3182253K->3115235K(8380096K), 0.0516111 secs] [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:37:08.277-0500: 553894.097: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 4.856/4.914 secs] [Times: user=5.67 sys=0.02, real=4.91 secs] 
2013-03-08T14:37:08.277-0500: 553894.097: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2013-03-08T14:37:08.325-0500: 553894.145: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.048/0.048 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
```

After:

```
2013-03-07T17:18:01.323-0500: 180055.128: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 10.765/20.646 secs] [Times: user=50.25 sys=3.32, real=20.65 secs] 
2013-03-07T17:18:01.323-0500: 180055.128: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2013-03-07T17:18:01.401-0500: 180055.206: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.076/0.078 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
2013-03-07T17:18:01.401-0500: 180055.206: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2013-03-07T17:18:03.074-0500: 180056.879: [GC 180056.880: [ParNew: 76670K->8512K(76672K), 0.1024039 secs] 5980843K->5922977K(8380096K), 0.1028797 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.04, real=0.10 secs] 
2013-03-07T17:18:05.447-0500: 180059.253: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 3.132/4.046 secs] [Times: user=3.94 sys=0.07, real=4.05 secs] 
2013-03-07T17:18:05.448-0500: 180059.254: [GC[YG occupancy: 51161 K (76672 K)]180059.254: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0243232 secs]180059.279: [weak refs processing, 0.2053571 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 5914465K(8303424K)] 5965627K(8380096K), 0.2569077 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.01, real=0.26 secs] 
2013-03-07T17:18:05.706-0500: 180059.512: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2013-03-07T17:18:12.511-0500: 180066.316: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 6.804/6.804 secs] [Times: user=13.98 sys=0.80, real=6.80 secs] 
2013-03-07T17:18:12.511-0500: 180066.316: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2013-03-07T17:18:12.558-0500: 180066.363: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.047/0.047 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.02, real=0.05 secs]
```

During these spikes, which lasted about a minute, the Tomcat server response time went from an average of 2ms to approximately 90 seconds.  After 3 days in production, we rolled back the changes and have not seen a CPU spike since.  Do you know of any changes in the JDK or Tomcat that may have caused this behavior?  One note:  this web application caches a very large amount of data in the heap (up to 3GB at startup).

Here are the JVM settings:

```
(Before) Tomcat 6 / JDK 1.6.0_18:
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_18"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -d64 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/env/tomcat-instance/logs/gc.log -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=(omitted) -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

(After) Tomcat 7 / JDK 1.6.0_38:
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_38"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -d64 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/env/tomcat-instance/logs/gc.log -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=(omitted) -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotal feedback - we hit a serious memory leak bug in 6u2n that has not been fixed until 7:

> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7013538
>
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7042582

6u21 is the safest Java 6 JRE that I have experience with.

Answer (score 0):

You upgraded both Tomcat and the JVM, so the spikes could be caused by either one of them. You can limit the number of threads for the GC.

`-XX:ParallelGCThreads=12`

If  you run more than one JVM, make sure there are not more GC threads than cores. Look into JVM 1.7, too.

Use these to see the effective jvm parameters and look for changes:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
-XX:+LogVMOutput
-XX:LogFile=logs/jvm.log
```